# Radio button selection A updates Radio button B

Tags: dojo, radio-button, lotus-notes

A requirement in an existing old'e school application requiring a popup to show radio selections and fields for the user to enter information, whereupon finishing with the popup, the radio selection from the popup updates the radio buttons showing on the web page spawning the popup.
The popup radio button field name is not needed and is not to be persisted in the notes document.

a.)  How to have one RadioGroup update the value in another RadioGroup?
b.)  How to make a throw-away radio field accept user selection, on the one had; but have the selected value update/persist in a different Field-name|Item?

[image]

Comment: Well, It seems like you have given same name to the radio buttons... because only one radio button can be selected from the collection of same name...

Comment: +Developerrr: There are two Radio Groups "DutyCode" & "RankSort". We can ignore one set and just make Shoreside/Shipboard popup refresh the underlying DutyCode Radio Group reflect the popup selection, in this case "Shipboard".

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I accomplished the radio update with dojo:

```
var queryString = "[name=" + currentNodeName + "]";
var targetNodeArray = dojo.query("[name=" + targetNodeName + "]");
if (targetNodeArray != null) {
    try {
        var ItemCheckedNode = dojo.query(queryString).filter(function(radio) {
            return radio.checked
        }).attr("value");

        dojo.forEach(targetNodeArray, function(radio) {
            if (ItemCheckedNode[0] === radio.value) {
                radio.checked = true;
                return radio.value;
            }
        })
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.toString);
    }
}
```

Personally, I Prefer updating the radio value via partialRefresh.